# Simple way to comprehend a list from a secondary list, only for ascending values

Tags: list, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have data in a pandas dataframe that consists of values that increase to a point, and then start decreasing. I am wondering how to simply extract the values up to the point at which they stop increasing.

For example,

```py
d = {'values' : [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

desired result = [1, 2, 3]
```

This is my attempt, which I thought would check to see if the current list index is larger than the previous, then move on:

```py
result = [i for i in df['values'] if df['values'][i-1] < df['values'][i]]
```

which returns

```py
[1, 2, 2, 1]
```

I'm unsure what is happening for that to be the result.

Edit:

Utilizing the `.diff()` function, suggested by Andrej, combined with list comprehension, I get the same result. (the numpy `np.isnan()` is used to include the first element of the difference list, which is NaN).

```py
result = [i for i in df['values'] 
if df['values'].diff().iloc[i]>0 
or np.isnan(df['values'].diff().iloc[i])]

result = [1, 2, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.diff()` to get difference between the values. If the values are increasing, the difference will be positive. So as next step do a `.cumsum()` of these values and search for maximum value:

```py
print(df.loc[: df["values"].diff().cumsum().idxmax()])
```

Prints:

```
   values
0       1
1       2
2       3
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrej - appreciated! I'm still keen on understanding the list comprehension. Do you understand why my method doesn't work? I tried to use the .diff() approach in a list comprehension and I got the same result as my initial method (see my edited question). This makes me think I don't understand how the list comprehension is happening.